# Add policy to AWS S3 that allows only specific domains, localhost, and access through the command line only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to create a S3 bucket policy that allows only specific domains, localhost, and access through the command line only.

I have this Policy but I am not sure:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowedAccessFromAllowedDomainsOnly",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BucketName",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BucketName/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://www.example.com/*",
                        "http://localhost/*"
                    ]
                },
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "127.0.0.1/32"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need someone to review this policy. and is it safe to use `aws:Referer` instead of an IP address?

Comment: Your policy only contains a `Deny` statement. Access to Amazon S3 buckets is **denied by default**. Therefore, there is no `Allow` policy that is granting any access to the bucket. Or will the access be performed using IAM credentials that have been granted access to the bucket by placing an `Allow` policy on the IAM User themselves?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have updated the policy and code as well. Please have a look

Comment: When specifying an IP address in an S3 Bucket Policy, you will need to provide a **public IP address**, not a private IP address such as `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: If you wish to grant access based on Referer _OR_ IP address, then you will need **two different statements**. As it is, all those requirements are being ANDed together, so they would need a correct Referer _AND_ a correct IP address.

Comment: What do you mean by "access through the command line"? It is not possible to restrict to "command line". Instead, you could restrict based on the IP address where the request is coming from or, better yet, use credentials with the AWS CLI and grant access by adding a policy to the IAM User rather than granting access via a Bucket Policy.

Comment: "Access through the command line" means I should use the command line to access my S3 bucket. If any IP is discovered, it should be inaccessible.

Comment: An API request _always_ comes from an IP address.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein What is the solution to this: `If you wish to grant access based on Referer OR IP address, then you will need two different statements. As it is, all those requirements are being ANDed together, so they would need a correct Referer AND a correct IP address.`

Comment: In your policy, create two statements. The `statements` section is a _list_ denoted by `[...]`. Add a second statement.

Answer (score 0):

> safe to use aws:Referer instead of an IP address

Sadly, its not safe. [AWS docs explicitly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-HTTP-HTTPS) warns against using `aws:Referer` as a safety measure:

> We recommend that you use caution when using the aws:Referer condition key. It is **dangerous to include a publicly** known HTTP referer header value. Unauthorized parties can use modified or custom browsers to provide any aws:Referer value that they choose. Therefore, **do not use aws:Referer to prevent unauthorized parties** from making direct AWS requests.

In other words, you can't use `aws:Referer` to enforce that only specific domains  can access (or not access) your bucket.

Comment: Ok, Then what is the solution to this? and review of my policy please.

Comment: @codeForCoffee The solution is proper authorization mechanism for your website, which requires users to login to your website to access the content.

Comment: It is already implemented

Comment: I can not add policy. It returned this error: `Invalid principal in policy`

Comment: @codeForCoffee Maybe its good that it failed. Policies with double negatives (Deny and NonPrinciple) are the most common cause of looking oneself out of the bucket.

Comment: Replacing NonPrincipal to Principal returned the same error

Comment: `Invalid principal in policy` means that IAM does not like the value you have provided for the `Principal` (`arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root`).